# Iron Router - Download and Redirect

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I want a user to be able to click a button to download a file and be redirected to the same view / stay there. I'm being able to download the file but then I can't redirect from this server route. Any ideas on how can I accomplish this? Thanks!

```
Router.route('/analytics-download', {
    name: "analytics-download",
    where: "server",
    action: function() {
      try {
        var filename = 'test.csv';
        var headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
          'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        this.response.end(data);
        // this.response.redirect('/analytics');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Instead of `this.response.redirect` why not just `Router.go('/analytics');`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I can't use Router.go in a server route.  I get Router.go is not a function

Comment: Ah, darn. Not sure how to pull this off server-side. The client is going to see the 200 and that's going to be it, it's not going to expect that to be followed by a 301.